# Showing a bipartite graph has a perfect matching.

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a bipartite graph with $n$ nodes on each side. Show
that if the degree of each vertex is greater than $n/2$, then $G$ has a perfect
matching.

My thoughts are to use the Marriage Theorem which my book states as

> A bipartite graph has a
>   perfect matching if and only if $|A| = |B|$ and for any subset of (say) $k$
>   nodes of $A$ there are at least $k$ nodes of $B$ that are connected to at least
>   one of them.

It is easy to show that any subset of $A$ of fewer than $n/2$ nodes is connected to at least $n/2$ nodes in $B$. However, I do not know how to conclude anything about bigger subsets of $A$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $X\subseteq A$ and $|X|\gt n/2$. Then **every** vertex in $B$ must be adjacent to a vertex in $X$, because any vertex in $B$ which is adjacent to no vertex in $X$ would have degree $\le|A|-|X|=n-|X|\lt n-n/2=n/2$.